# Implement caching in a way that on new build upload no cache clearing required

Tags: javascript, angular, caching, webpack, browser-cache

I have developed my project on angular 2 using **webpack**. Whenever I deploy my new build, the **client side needs to clear the cache** in order to view the changes which had been made by code. Below is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const typescript = require('typescript');
const { AotPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');

const rules = [
  { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader' },
  { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
  { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: 'file-loader' }
];

const plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    }
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',
    minChunks: (module) => module.context && /node_modules/.test(module.context)
  })
];


rules.push({
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loaders: [
    'awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular-router-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'
    ]
});

plugins.push(
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.resolve(__dirname, './notfound')),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
    minimize: true,
    debug: false
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    sourceMap: true,
    beautify: false,
    mangle: {
        screw_ie8: true
    },
    compress: {
        unused: true,
        dead_code: true,
        drop_debugger: true,
        conditionals: true,
        evaluate: true,
        drop_console: true,
        sequences: true,
        booleans: true,
        screw_ie8: true,
        warnings: false
    },
    comments: false
    })
);


module.exports = {
  cache: true,
  context: __dirname,
  devServer: {
    contentBase: __dirname,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: {
      chunks: true,
      chunkModules: true,
      chunkOrigins: true,
      errors: true,
      errorDetails: true,
      hash: true,
      timings: true,
      modules: true,
      warnings: true
    },
    publicPath: './build/',
    port: 3000
  },
  devtool: 'sourcemap',
  entry: {
    app: ['zone.js/dist/zone', './app/main.ts']
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: 'lfd6093bc62332f579200891cc0e9c8[name].js',
    publicPath: './build/',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  },
  node: {
    console: true,
    global: true,
    process: true,
    Buffer: false,
    setImmediate: false
  },
  module: {
    rules
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    modules: [
      'app',
      'node_modules'
    ]
  },
  plugins
};
```

Is there a way in which I can overcome this on **client side only** ?
If there isn't my last resort will be to check api version and give pop-up to the user to clear the cache.

Comment: `output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js'`, try this.

Comment: Thanks. chunkhash helped instead of contenthash.

Comment: Glad to help. I'm going to write an answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack does not know if files changed, by default, but you can help webpack by changing output filename and put a `contenthash` on it:

`output: { filename: '[name].[contenthash].js'}`

By doing this, a hash based on the file content is going to be generated, if the file content change, this hash change so webpack knows that it has to rebuild everything.